# UIImagePickerController's didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is too slow, can I add progressHUD/indicator?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

For the UIImagePickerController, I opened the

```
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

so that user can move and scale the photo, after capturing or selecting from album. Once the "choose" or "use" is clicked, the whole app is frozen for more than 5 seconds, and then goes back with the photos, through

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

I tried to add an indicator in this delegate function, but it doesn't appear... I guess, the long delay happens before this callback, and is probably because of the "editing" from ful

Is there any possible way to handle this? I just wish to give the users a good experience. :)

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

You should perform this on another thread and with an NSAutoreleasePool, like so:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
   [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(uploadImage:) toTarget:self withObject:image];  
}

- (void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)image {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   // Handle chosen photo
   [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but as I tried, nothing changed... still a delay after click the "choose" ....

Comment: Are you doing anything to the image, or in the didFinishPickingImage code block?  It should all be done within the NSAutoreleasePool and [pool release]..

Comment: Dear Kolin, everything is done within the uploadImage function... my codes exactly followed yours :)

Comment: What kind of stuff are you doing inside the code block?  For me, it sped things up instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the UIImagePicker from the main thread?

This code should be called from there. Every time I have this exact 5 seconds delay on anything UI-related, it is because the code is being called from another thread, instead the main one.